# Amasty google invisible captcha

Tags: magento2, captcha, amasty

I have an issue with the default form `Customer Create Account` from Amasty google invisible captcha V3 which is never submitting and I have no idea why.

[image: captcha config]

In front page, the captcha is appearing.

[image: captcha front]

But sadly, once I submit the form; the form action is never called, I see the `amasty_invisible_token` html input field being updated; but that's basically all what the submit is doing.

PS1 : The captcha seems to work fine on the other default forms

PS2 : If I delete `Customer Create Account` from the config, I don't have amasty captcha on the form and the form is submitted properly.

When I try to submit the form with amasty, this is what seems to be called

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6LcdvG4b0XgXyr5-O

The response looks like this :

[image: response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research we figure it out that the issue was coming from the following modules allowing to connect to the user account from the backoffice.

Disabling these modules fixed our captcha issue.

`bin/magento module:disable Magento_LoginAsCustomer Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi Magento_LoginAsCustomerGraphQl Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache Magento_LoginAsCustomerQuote Magento_LoginAsCustomerSales`

Comment: Thanks Claims, that works like a charm. I wonder why amasty does not added it as a note somewhere in there documentation when there is a clear issue. 
For me I had to do
`bin/magento module:disable Magento_LoginAsCustomer Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi Magento_LoginAsCustomerGraphQl Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog Magento_LoginAsCustomerLogging Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache Magento_LoginAsCustomerQuote Magento_LoginAsCustomerSales Magento_LoginAsCustomerWebsiteRestriction`